# How to fetch the document mode of Internet Explorer in JAVA

Tags: java, javascript, internet-explorer

I am trying to fetch the document mode of the browser i.e IE from the given function.I knew that in javascript we can use `document.documentMode` to fetch the doucment mode of IE. But is there any way to do it in java ? I have the `userAgent` string fro the `HttpServletRequest` ,but I cannot use it to fetch the document mode.I have used `ScriptEngine` to execute the javascript inside the java code ,but It is giving exception that the document element is not defined.Kindly help please

```
 ScriptEngine engine = 
            new ScriptEngineManager().getEngineByName("javascript");
    String docversio = null;
    String script = "function documentversion() { return document.documentMode }";
    try {
         engine.eval(script);

         Invocable inv = (Invocable)engine;

        try {
            docversio = (String) inv.invokeFunction("documentversion");
        } catch (NoSuchMethodException e) {
            System.out.println("No such method");
            e.printStackTrace();
        } 

        if(null != docversio)
        System.out.println("the document version is "+docversio);
    } catch (ScriptException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Comment: This is servlet code, isn't it? So it runs on the server?

Comment: Yes and this code snippet is inside a method which is getting called from doGET().

Comment: But when it runs on the server, how can you expect that it will change something on the client?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are doing here executes JavaScript on the server side. What you need is JavaScript on the client's browser. One way to achieve what you want is to pass on the documentMode as a URL param. This will be available on the server.

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
if ( document.referrer == null || document.referrer.indexOf(window.location.hostname) < 0 ) {
   window.location.href = window.location.href + "?documentMode=" + document.documentMode;
}
});
</script>
```

Now the URL param documentMode will be available with `request.getParameter("documentMode")`

Answer (score 0):

```
public class DocumentModeOfIE extends HttpServlet {
  private String documentMode;

  public void init(ServletConfig config) throws ServletException {    }

  public void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) 
       throws ServletException, IOException {
    PrintWriter out = resp.getWriter();
    resp.setContentType("text/html");
    documentMode = req.getHeader("X-UA-Compatible");
    out.println(documentMode);
  }

  public void destroy() {  }

}
```